Late 90s/early 2000s cyberpunk/post-apocalyptic cartoon series starring a female soldier called Mayday
I watched this series in Sri Lanka in late 2002 or early 2003, on a channel called Art TV, along side Mega Babies and Extreme Ghostbusters, in a block called crazy cartoons. Don't know if that will help narrow it down.
It was clearly a western animation, but with anime influence. Might've been one of those french animations that were popular at the time. Or a pilot to an unaired series. They only aired this single episode over and over.
I got the impression that it was not a series meant for kids. Might've been a dubbed anime. But I'm not sure. I think it was a European cartoon that tried to mimic the anime aesthetic.
It started with a sort of female soldier tied to a hospital bed in underground bunker or airport. There's a commanding officer, whom she argues with saying she doesn't want to be there. She has a husky/sexy voice and is basically a femme fatale. She is in the hospital because she's injured and not fit for duty. The commanding officer basically injects her with a serum and gives her some gear and sends off on her way after a briefing.
The bad guy she is after is someone she has a personal vendetta against. He is a cyborg like Dr. X from Action Man, or Metallo from DC/Superman. The show had a grey colour palette. Mayday had spiky anime-ish hair and grey outfit with a grey backpack.
There is a fight on a plane and Mayday ends up parachuting or something and ends up infiltrating the bad guy's hideout. It ends with her and the cyborg dangling from metal cables, and Mayday being all smug and cutting them while the cyborg falls to his death.
Then her commanding officer arrives on a plane and Mayday points at the scorch marks on the airport ground and says "like what I've done with the place?"
The setting was a mix of cyberpunk gadgets in a post apocalyptic setting.
This is all I can remember about the show. I was like 6 or 7 when I watched it.

Do you recall the hair colour of the main character?

@LogicDictates Grey, or a greyish blue,

I wonder if you might be talking about season 1, episode 2 of G.I. Joe Extreme.
The full episode is on YouTube.
Details that fit:

Near the beginning (about 1:35) the character (named Mayday) is injured and in a hospital bed talking to her commander.

The "like what I've done with the place" line happens as you describe it at about 19 minutes in

The cable cutting scene is at about 17 minutes

The leader of the villains does look like a cyborg

There are also robot troopers on the villains' side that look like Metallo


Details which don't fit:

The Mayday character doesn't have spiky anime hair


OMG YES!
THIS IS IT !
HOW DO I MARK THIS AS THE CORRECT ANSWER???
Yeah I might've remembered some of the details wrong, but THIS WAS IT!
